# Trying to check notifications from other apps

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications

In my app, I need to be alerted of user notifications from other apps as they are delivered to the Mac's Notification Center (Mavericks). I've seen the `NSUserNotificationCenter` class, and have been querying it using

```
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliveredNotifications]
```

However, it is only returning notifications raised by my own app. Is there any publicly available method to do this, or do I need to look deeper?

Comment: Since they is a sandboxing for MacAppStore apps, I'd say that you can't do it if your app is for MacAppStore, you can't. It seems that only signed apps can't use the Notification Center.

Comment: I'm not planning on using the App Store. As far as I'm aware, both signed and unsigned apps can post to and read from the notification centre.